# A checkbox data type and showing more than one row per "row" (in Adazzle react-data-grid)

Tags: react-data-grid

We'd like to use React Data Grid from Adazzle (as mentioned in the tag with this question) now that we're using React (16.xx) and the older jsGrid is less appealing.

Two questions:

1. Our old jsGrid had a data type to include in the grid called Checkbox. This was immensely helpful. I haven't found a similar type in the React Grid. Have I just missed it or is it not a part of the library?
2. In each row, in some columns, we'd like to actually have two rows of data inside the column -- i.e., two lines of text separated by carriage return. But the react-data-grid demos only seem to show one line per column. Is this a limitation, or can we use CSS in the values inside columns?
3. Is there search included for the rows shown in the table at any given point in time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will provide answer to your question part by part 
1) In react-data-grid column you can include a checkbox by using the formatter
attribute that is specified while the columns are defined.
Consider the following example

```
let columns = [
      {
        key: 'name',
        name: 'Name',
        resizable: true,
        width: 100
      },
{
        key: 'checkbox',
        name: 'CheckBox',
        formatter:checkBoxFormatter,
        resizable: true,
        width: 100
      }
]
class checkBoxFormatter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CheckBox></Checkbox> //Provide your checkbox code here
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

2)You can exapand the rows for that you need to use `getSubRowDetails` and `onCellExpand` attributes of `ReactDataGrid` component .For example refer [this](https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/#/examples/tree-view) documentation

3)Search is available for filtering .For example refer [this](https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/#/examples/filterable-grid) documentation